# In Outlook, how do I give one instance of a recurring meeting to someone else?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have a weekly meeting at which I am the only attendee. It represents something that has to be done at a particular time every Tuesday. When I am out of town and can't do it, I can invite someone else to that instance, which succeeds in getting it on their calendar. However I don't seem to be able to get it off my calendar, which messes up my view of all the things I am doing out of town.

[image]

Even though I am the organizer, and do not want to be removed from all the other instances of the meeting, can I somehow be removed from just this one? Failing that, can I arrange for this instance not to appear on my calendar, to make more room for other things?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove yourself from that one meeting by deleting that single occurrence, which won't have any impact on the rest of the scheduled occurrences for that event.

#### To delete a single occurrence from your Outlook calendar:

- Double click on that event/meeting on your calendar.
- When prompted whether to open that particular instance or the entire series, choose that instance (labeled "Just this one" in Outlook 2013) and click **OK**.
- Click **Delete** in the ribbon at the top of the window.
- You'll be prompted to choose if you want to delete the entire series or just that instance; select that instance only. (Choose "Delete this occurrence", then click **OK**.)

The instructions above are for Outlook 2013, but should be similar for other versions.