# "Decline" an occurrence of my own recurring meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meeting-request

I have a recurring meeting for which I am the organizer. In my org people clear out meetings when they have planned out of office so that others can quickly see who is attending those meetings. While clearing out my out of office days, I came across a recurring meeting for which I am the organizer. As this is a cross team sync meeting, it should still continue in my absence, but I want to remove myself from the occurrence in order to clear out my schedule.

I found this question [In Outlook, how do I give one instance of a recurring meeting to someone else?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250405/in-outlook-how-do-i-give-one-instance-of-a-recurring-meeting-to-someone-else/1250712#1250712) which seems to be asking either the same question, or one very similar, but perhaps because of a different Outlook version or maybe the specific circumstances here I don't have the same options as this user did. When I go into the occurrence of this meeting I only have the option to cancel meeting (which I don't want to do), not "decline" occurrence. My current workaround is to leave it on my calendar but mark myself as out of office for the time of this meeting, which seems inelegant. Can someone let me know if there's a better solution here?

For reference, I have Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365

Update:
I just realized that changing it from busy to out of office was for all attendees, not just myself, so I've reverted it back to as it was. Unfortunately, now I have no workaround, so looking for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is available. Refer to the following steps:

1.Go to the Send / Receive tab, and then click to highlight the Work Offline button.

[image]

2.Confirm the status bar is as shown in the below figure:

[image]

3.Go to the Calendar view and choose the occurrence of your own recurring meeting, and press "Delete" key on the keyboard.

4.Select "Delete this occurrence" and click OK.

[image]

5.Then click Send Cancellation.

[image]

6.Then switch to Mail view, now the cancellation email will be stuck in the Outbox. Just select the cancellation email and press "Delete" key on the keyboard.

7.Click the Work offline button to connect to the internet again.

In this way, your canceled meeting will not be sent to others and just be deleted from your own calendar.

Comment: That is.. incredibly convoluted, but I will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Look forward to your good news!

Comment: Sadly, outlook is too smart. It didn't remove the appointment because it has some handshaking with the exchange server and it knows that the cancellation was not applied.